# Cannot read property 'items' of undefined on NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

i've get problem in my project code.

I develop website for Online Shop purpose, honestly i'm using template from GitHub for faster production ( My lecture said ). Product working as well but Categories can't working as my expectation.

I'm using Next.js and this first time use FullStack on JavaScript. I'm wanna call my API from MongoDB with Axios and there have categories field within data type Array. This file i haven't change anyword.

Error said :

> Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

This my line code inventoryByCategory.js :

```
function inventoryByCategory (inventory) {
  return inventory.reduce((acc, next) => {
    const categories = next.categories
    categories.forEach(c => {
      if (acc[c]) {
        acc[c].items.push(next)
      } else {
        acc[c] = {}
        acc[c].items = []
        acc[c].items.push(next)
      }
    })
    return acc
  }, {})
}

export {
  inventoryByCategory
}
```

This my data fecthing on inventoryProvider.js

```
import axios from "axios"

async function fetchInventory() {
  const inventory = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/inventory')
                          .then((response) => response.data.data)
  
  return Promise.resolve(inventory)
}

export {
  fetchInventory
}
```

And this my error show up in inventoryForCategory.js  :

```
import { fetchInventory } from './inventoryProvider'
import { inventoryByCategory } from './inventoryByCategory'

async function inventoryForCategory (category) {
  const inventory = await fetchInventory()
  const byCategory = inventoryByCategory(inventory)
  return byCategory[category].items
}

export default inventoryForCategory
```

I think this enough information for you, thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is category? Can you log category right above your error statement to see what it is. Will it exist on your returned object?

Comment: @TusharShahi I have a data array in a category field in my database, I have never changed the file. and this is my first time using nextjs

Comment: I understand but it will be much better if you use console.log() to see what you are getting at different steps. That will help you understand and also let us know what is happening.

Comment: What does console.log(inventory) log? Also, you do not need Promse.resolve(inventory) you can simply return inventory since you have already awaited the promise.

Comment: console.log(inventory) return my data as expectation. But thanks for suggestion helping me. But my problem on inventoryForCategory.js if i change to console.log() and return it. Result it's {
  'Category 1': { items: [ [Object] ] },
  Category 2: { items: [ [Object] ] },
  Category 3: { items: [ [Object] ] }
}